# Alternative to componentWillMount to register axios interceptors? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So here's the problem.

I want to register interceptors on request and response of my `axios` instance to catch errors. I have a `withErrorHandler` named wrapper component that kind of handles the error logic.

I need to update the state whenever an HTTP request is sent and whenever there's an error in the HTTP response. I need to register the interceptor before the `render` method is called or before `componentDidMount`.

The job of this `withErrorHandler` component is to show an overlay/modal with an error message. The overlay/modal is conditionally shown based on the value of `this.state.error` which is either `null` or an object returned from the HTTP request. The only way that I've been able to make this work is if I register the interceptors in the `componentWillMount` method.

If I try to register the interceptor in the `constructor`, the error overlay/modal doesn't show because (I think), I'm not allowed to update the state in the `constructor` which the interceptors do.

```
const withErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
  return class extends Component {
    state = {
  error: null,
};

constructor() {
  super();
  this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
    this.setState({ error: null }); // the interceptor is updating state in the constructor
    return req;
  });
  this.resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => res,
    (error) => {
      this.setState({ error: error });
    }
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  axios.interceptors.request.eject(this.reqInterceptor);
  axios.interceptors.response.eject(this.resInterceptor);
}

errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
  this.setState({ error: null });
};

render() {
  return (
    <Auxiliary>
      <Modal
        show={this.state.error}
        modalClosed={this.errorConfirmedHandler}
      >
        {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
      </Modal>
      <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    </Auxiliary>
  );
}
  };
};
```

This doesn't work and I don't get my error overlay/modal.

As I said, if I do this in the `componentDidMount` method, it doesn't work. The only way that I've been able to make it work is if I use `componentWillMount`, which as you know as been depreciated.

Everywhere I go, I'm told that I'm supposed to replace `componentWillMount` with `constructor` but the constructor isn't working. What's the solution here?

Comment: Are you making the axios request within the WrappedComponent?

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2315) on github that might point you in the right direction. Seems like a separate module is the way to go. Which means you would need to decouple your business logic from your visual component

Comment: I am making the axios request inside the WrappedComponent, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same course. I got it to work by putting the constructor directly inside the anonymous, class-based component that gets returned by withErrorHandler. I initialize the state within the constructor as well. I'm not sure, but the issue might be that you're setting state before you call the constructor.

```
const withErrorHandler = ( WrappedComponent, axios ) => {
    return class extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                error: null
            };
            axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({error: null});
                return req;
            })
            axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
                this.setState({error: error});
                console.log("Error: " + error.message);
            });
        }
```

Of course, you could assign the interceptors to variables here in order to eject them in componentWillUnmount below.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, state cannot be set in the constructor so this doesn't work.